# Can't display Unicode chars with Flask

Tags: python, unicode, flask, jinja2

I have some strings in my database with Unicode chars that I can't display properly on my website. However it works correctly in one situation which is interesting.

So it works when I do this:

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('home.html', text = '\u00e9ps\u00e9g')
# displays: épség
```

But it does not work when I do this (query the database and pass the string from result):

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    text_string = getText()
    return render_template('home.html', text = text_string )
# displays: \u00e9ps\u00e9g
```

However when I use exactly the same string that I get from the second version with the first solution it works perfectly.

I am interested to discover why the first solution works and the second does not. Both string should be the same, but when I get it from the server it stays the same when I display it. When I add it manually it's good again. However unfortunately I have hundreds of strings so I need to use the second one.

Comment: can you check `type('\u00e9ps\u00e9g')` and `type(text_string)`?

Comment: Can you provide the code of your getText() method?

Comment: @NilsWerner I got <class 'str'> for both.

Comment: Unicode strings in python2 are denoted as u'xyz'.

Comment: @NasefKhan I'm using python 3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in one case is *unicode-escape* sequences that represent a single Unicode character.  In the other case you have literal characters \,u,... that represent six characters.  this can be illustrated using raw strings, which ignore Unicode escape sequences:

```
>>> text = '\u00e9ps\u00e9g'
>>> print(text)
épség
>>> text = r'\u00e9ps\u00e9g'
>>> print(text)
\u00e9ps\u00e9g
```

To convert a Unicode string with literal escape sequences, first you need a byte string, then decode with the `unicode_escape` codec.  To obtain a byte string from a Unicode string with literal escape codes for non-ASCII characters, encode it with the `ascii` codec:

```
>>> text = r'\u00e9ps\u00e9g'
>>> print(text)
\u00e9ps\u00e9g
>>> print(text.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape'))
épség
```

From your comment you may have text from a JSON data file.  If it is proper JSON, this should decode it:

```
>>> s = r'"\u00e9ps\u00e9g \ud83c\udf0f"'
>>> print(s)
"\u00e9ps\u00e9g \ud83c\udf0f"
>>> print(json.loads(s))
épség
```

Note that a JSON string is quoted.  It would not decode without the double-quotes.

Comment: Thank you Mark! It's working almost perfectly. However with some emojis like `\ud83c\udf0f` I get an error `utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83c' in position 4851: surrogates not allowed`. Do you have an idea what can cause this? These are complete "emoji codes", I don't understand what's the problem with them.

Comment: @rihe The source of your text may be a JSON data file.  JSON encodes Unicode characters above U+FFFF as UTF-16 surrogate pairs.  I'll add an example.

Comment: Yes, it was JSON and I also forget the double-quotes, but now it is totally perfect! Amazing answer!